# PostgreSQL - Generate a list of users who logged in today and also at least once in the next seven days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a user_id, first_hit_at::date and last_hit_at::date like the following.

```
user_id .  first_hit_at .  last_hit_at
    1        2017-01-01     2017-01-01
    2        2017-01-01     2017-01-01
    3        2017-01-01     2017-01-01
    4        2017-01-01     2017-01-01
    5        2017-01-01 .   2017-01-01
    6        2017-01-01     2017-01-01
    7        2017-01-01 .   2017-01-01
    8        2017-01-01 .   2017-01-01
    9        2017-01-01 .   2017-01-01
```

Desired output:

```
count(distinct_id)        date
    3                     2017-01-01
    2                     2017-01-02
    1                     2017-01-03
    2                     2017-01-04
```

I want to count the users who if logged in today, they also logged in at least once in the next 7 days
 SQL query that I wrote:

```
select 
   a.user_id, 
   first_hit_at::date,
   row_number() over(partition by a.user_id order by first_hit_at) as rn
from stg_marketing.ga_sessions a
  where first_hit_at::date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
  and user_login_state = 'true'
  --and first_hit_at::date > '7'
order by 2,3 asc;
```

Comment: are you sure the desired output corresponds to what the description is?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala: Yes I want to count the number of users who if logged in today and also logged in the next 7 days at least once.

Comment: I assume that "they also logged in at least once in the next 7 days " means the *previous* seven days.  Future logins seem unlikely to be recorded in the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have edited the post, the table has both the fields, first_hit_at and last_hit_at and I want the user count who logged in today and in the next 7 days as in future. Thanks

Comment: @chiragkalra You should avoid changing your question once you have asked it, as it runs the risk of invalidating the work which other people have already done to help you.

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

I would think of aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select user_id
from stg_marketing.ga_sessions s
where s.first_hit_at >= current_date - interval '7 day'
group by s.user_id
having max(first_hit_at) >= current_date and
       min(first_hit_at) < current_date();
```

Comment: Please check the post again. I have made some edits in it. Thanks